# proof of Lehmann-Scheffe theorem

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I'm reading proof of Lehmann-Scheffe theorem in *Casella's Statistical Inference (2nd ed)*
Theorem states that

> Let $T$ be a complete sufficient statistic for a parameter $\theta$, and let $\phi(T)$be any estimator based only on T.
> Then $\phi(T)$is the unique best unbiased estimator of its expected value

To prove $\phi(T)$ is best unbiased estimator, he use following lemma

> Suppose $EW = \tau(\theta)$. Then $W$ is best unbiased estimator of $\tau(\theta)$ if and only if $W$ is uncorrelated with all unbiased estimator of $0$

Then he states proof of Lehmann-Scheffe theorem as follows:

1. Since $T$ is complete, there are no unbiased estimator of $0$ that are based on $T$
2. **By Rao-Blackwell Theorem, It suffices to consider unbiased estimator of $0$ based on $T$**
3. Hence, $\phi(T)$ is uncorrelated to all unbiased estimator of $0$ (as there is only one unbiased estimator of $0$, just $0$ itself.)
4. So by lemma, we got desired result

I cannot understand second step.

If we deal with to find or check best unbiased estimator, I think we can use Rao-Blackwell theorem since estimator based on $T$ always has smaller variance.
But in here, we want to check whether $\phi(T)$ is **uncorrelated** to all unbiased estimator of $0$, so I think it's not sufficient to check only estimator based on $T$.

How can I solve this problem?

(Indeed, I have other proof of Lehmann-Scheffe theorem. I just want to know how this proof make sense)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the possibility that there is a better unbiased estimator. The Rao-Backwell theorem says that the expected value of that unbiased estimator given $T$ has variance that is less than or equal to the original estimator. That means this improved estimator (which is a function of $T$) can be considered instead as the "better estimator". I other words, if I can show my estimator beats that one, then it also beats the original one.

Can you tell me where this proof is? The statement is **Theorem 7.3.23**, but I don't see the proof.

Your question is related to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449486/rao-blackwell-part-of-the-lehmann-scheffe-theorem).

Comment: I think he explained its proof in example 7.3.22. Indeed, in this example, he claimed that $\frac{n}{n+1}Y$ is best unbiased estimator using this argument.